# Backpack upload files to a directory based on record id

Tags: laravel-backpack

For fields of type upload or upload_multiple, I have a mutator that moves the uploaded file to a hard-coded location on disk (for example, 'photos\').

I need to save those files in directories based on the record IDs. So if I edit record with id 5, for example, I want the photos to be saved in 'photos\5\'.
This would be of interest when adding a new record as well.

How can I do this?
Thanks so much for helping.

Answer (score 0):

You'll notice in the [upload field type documentation](https://laravel-backpack.readme.io/docs/crud-fields#section-upload) there's a mutator. Inside that mutator you can use `$this->id` to get the current entry's ID.

Cheers!

Comment: I figured this one out, by using $this->getKey() on the model (works just the same) for the case when the record is edited. However I still don't know how to solve this for the case when the record is just being added, thus $this->id doesn't have a value there.

Thank you.